# Unbound grid with different kinds of controls in one column

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, treeview, grid

I am looking for a WinForms or WPF grid that is able to display different controls (textboxes and comboboxes for now) in the same column. It must have treelist/treeview functionality too, so that the hierarchy between rows (nodes) is visible. I need to be able to add a control at runtime to a cell and change row heights and column widths programmatically.
I've been searching for a while but no luck so far. Any suggestions? Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The results of this answer.

[image]

I would use the standard WPF DataGrid, there is no need to pay money just yet, you can select a Template column and just do a little data binding inside it, the example below has a very simple class that I'm binding to the grid.

```
public class ListItemType
{
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

This class can obviously be anything but in the example I'm setting type to either 1 or 2, any object in the bound list that has a type of 1 is given a button to represent it and anything with a Type=2 is given a CheckBox to represent it.

the XAML for the datagrid looks like this. (indentation ++)

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>

        <!-- The template coloumn -->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>

                    <!-- Each cell is put in to a content presenter so I can change it's content -->
                    <ContentPresenter>
                        <ContentPresenter.Content>
                            <Binding Path="Type">
                                <Binding.Converter>
                                    <local:SwitchConverter>

                                        <local:SwitchConverterCase When="1">
                                            <Button Content="{Binding Text}"></Button>
                                        </local:SwitchConverterCase>

                                        <local:SwitchConverterCase When="2">
                                            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Text}" />
                                        </local:SwitchConverterCase>


                                    </local:SwitchConverter>
                                </Binding.Converter>
                            </Binding>
                        </ContentPresenter.Content>
                    </ContentPresenter>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The switch converter used above is just a generic converter that simplifies XAML code a bit, you could use any converter you want but here is the code for the one I used anyway.

```
/// <summary>
/// A converter that accepts <see cref="SwitchConverterCase"/>s and converts them to the 
/// Then property of the case.
/// </summary>
[ContentProperty("Cases")]
public class SwitchConverter : IValueConverter
{
    // Converter instances.
    List<SwitchConverterCase> _cases;

    #region Public Properties.
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets an array of <see cref="SwitchConverterCase"/>s that this converter can use to produde values from.
    /// </summary>
    public List<SwitchConverterCase> Cases { get { return _cases; } set { _cases = value; } }
    #endregion
    #region Construction.
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="SwitchConverter"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public SwitchConverter()
    {
        // Create the cases array.
        _cases = new List<SwitchConverterCase>();
    }
    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The value produced by the binding source.</param>
    /// <param name="targetType">The type of the binding target property.</param>
    /// <param name="parameter">The converter parameter to use.</param>
    /// <param name="culture">The culture to use in the converter.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// A converted value. If the method returns null, the valid null value is used.
    /// </returns>
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // This will be the results of the operation.
        object results = null;

        // I'm only willing to convert SwitchConverterCases in this converter and no nulls!
        if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("value");

        // I need to find out if the case that matches this value actually exists in this converters cases collection.
        if (_cases != null && _cases.Count > 0)
            for (int i = 0; i < _cases.Count; i++)
            {
                // Get a reference to this case.
                SwitchConverterCase targetCase = _cases[i];

                // Check to see if the value is the cases When parameter.
                if (value == targetCase || value.ToString().ToUpper() == targetCase.When.ToString().ToUpper())
                {
                    // We've got what we want, the results can now be set to the Then property
                    // of the case we're on.
                    results = targetCase.Then;

                    // All done, get out of the loop.
                    break;
                }
            }

        // return the results.
        return results;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The value that is produced by the binding target.</param>
    /// <param name="targetType">The type to convert to.</param>
    /// <param name="parameter">The converter parameter to use.</param>
    /// <param name="culture">The culture to use in the converter.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// A converted value. If the method returns null, the valid null value is used.
    /// </returns>
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Represents a case for a switch converter.
/// </summary>
[ContentProperty("Then")]
public class SwitchConverterCase
{
    // case instances.
    string _when;
    object _then;

    #region Public Properties.
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the condition of the case.
    /// </summary>
    public string When { get { return _when; } set { _when = value; } }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the results of this case when run through a <see cref="SwitchConverter"/>
    /// </summary>
    public object Then { get { return _then; } set { _then = value; } }
    #endregion
    #region Construction.
    /// <summary>
    /// Switches the converter.
    /// </summary>
    public SwitchConverterCase()
    {
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="SwitchConverterCase"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="when">The condition of the case.</param>
    /// <param name="then">The results of this case when run through a <see cref="SwitchConverter"/>.</param>
    public SwitchConverterCase(string when, object then)
    {
        // Hook up the instances.
        this._then = then;
        this._when = when;
    }
    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a <see cref="System.String"/> that represents this instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// A <see cref="System.String"/> that represents this instance.
    /// </returns>
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("When={0}; Then={1}", When.ToString(), Then.ToString());
    }
}
```

Finally for the treeview component that you require.. you can actually put even another datagrid inside each cell to achieve whatever level of depth you require.

Comment: This looks like it has all I'm looking for. I'll check this one out asap, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find that a standard WPF TreeView with some clever templating will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

If paying money for such a component is an option, I would highly recommend Telerik components. They have lot's of controls and the technical support is great.

You can have a look at the some examples to find out if their products suit your needs:

[Telerik GridView for WPF](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/gridview.aspx)

[Telerik TreeListView for WPF](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/treelistview.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Matthias for your fast reply, this is an option and I will check it out :)